# Opening QR Code reader app from URL

Tags: applications

When using Android and ZXing for reading QR codes, one can open the link http://zxing.appspot.com/scan to start the/a QR reader app (as mentioned here at [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent))

Are there any similar ways to activate a QR reader from an URL for iPhone?

Comment: If I may ask: what is it that you want to archieve?

Comment: Want to build an 'app' that is a webpage. Preferably work for both iPhone and Android. Got this working as wanted for Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [linked example](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) reveals that you would like to use a concept called [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Unfortunately, these are [not available on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630874/is-there-android-intent-concept-in-iphone-sdk). As explained in the latter article, you could try to experiment with [custom URL schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) on iOS ([this](http://www.pic2shop.com/developers.html) may be pretty much what you want, but with a different scanning app) ... Experiment!